# hide empty row from Mat table angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

i have app for angular 13 i use mat table and i want to display icon for downloading file but i want to hide this icon when the link is not existing yet.
html code

```
</ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="fileUrl">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> url </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <a [href]="setFile(element.fileUrl)" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i></a></td>
      </ng-container>
```

Ts code:

```
 setFile(url:string) {
if(url !=null){
  this.DisplayFileUrl=this.congesService.getFilePath(url)
  return this.DisplayFileUrl
}
```

someone can help me pls
thinks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
setFile(url:string) {
if(url !=null){
  this.DisplayFileUrl=this.congesService.getFilePath(url)
  return this.DisplayFileUrl
} else return null; 
}
```

And in your html:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="fileUrl">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> url </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <a *ngIf="setFile(element.fileUrl)" [href]="setFile(element.fileUrl)" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i></a></td>
</ng-container>
```

ngIf does the magic!

Greetings, Flo

Comment: It's better iterate over the data and add a new property "iconVisible". In general it's not a good idea use a function in the .html -else if a very little function-. Remember that Angular should execute the functions in .html to know if some has changed -you can see if you write in your function a `console.log('it's executed the function')`-